# Move data from cells to the end of an existing row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to move data from rows where columns A and B are empty to the end of the previous row where column A and B have values using VBA.

From

[image: Initial Data]

To

[image: Rearranged Data]

To do this I was thinking of iterating through the Range of cells with a While Wend command but don't know how to actually get the text to move to the end of the row without knowing the cell number at the end of the previous row in advance.

Comment: Are the items with multiple entries in column 4 contained within a single cell as it appears from your screenshot? Or are there really multiple rows.  If the former, it's just a matter of splitting the column on the LF character (done simply in Power Query).

Answer (score 0):

There's probably better ways but this works (assuming that values in column D are all individual rows/cells)

```
Sub script()
 For Each cell In Range("A1:A15")
   Do Until cell.Offset(1, 0) <> "" Or cell.Offset(1, 3) = ""
     With cell
       .Offset(1, 0).End(xlToRight).Copy cell.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1)
       .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
     End With
   Loop
 Next cell
End Sub
```